# Drupal 7 Click tracking / traffic per node

Tags: drupal, click, drupal-7, tracking

I'd like to track the number of times a node shows up in search results, the number of times it's clicked on in a search result, and the number of times it is displayed. I'd like all of this information to be readily available - perhaps stored in the content type? I could use some help determining the best practice here.

Alternatively. Could I use google analytics to track all of this somehow such that I could access the results from a custom designed module (which, can anyone point me in a direction on?)

Ultimately I want uses to look at a node and be able to see how much traffic came from in-site linking, off-site linking, and how many times users followed a link from the node to an external website.

Can I export google analytic data for each node somehow to drupal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any existing Druapl module site can accomplish that, but some study on Google Analytics can get you there,

> the number of times it's clicked on in a search result, and the number
>   of times it is displayed.

can be done by inserting [events tracker](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).

> Ultimately I want uses to look at a node and be able to see how much
>   traffic came from in-site linking, off-site linking, and how many
>   times users followed a link from the node to an external website.

is largely already built-in GA, and you can use conversion if you need some stats which is a bit more complex.

> Can I export google analytic data for each node somehow to drupal

GA can export data in csv, you can automate([API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html)) that to feed the data back to Druapl tho.

You might want to ask on [webmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site if you decide going for the GA

Answer (score 0):

So how is what you're looking for any different than - http://drupal.org/project/click

Other than that there isn't yet a Drupal 7 version of this module?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [click](http://drupal.org/project/click) for Drupal 7 click thru external link tracking/logging might be: [pop_links](https://drupal.org/project/pop_links)
(currently a development release in Drupal 7)